# problem organizing data

Tags: java, sql, swing

I have a table as given below

```
RMG Date        Value
YA  11/02/2001  94
YB  11/02/2011  63
YC  11/02/2011  35
YA  12/02/2011  32
YB  12/02/2011  45
YC  12/02/2011  51
YA  13/02/2011  32
YB  13/02/2011  45
YC  13/02/2011  51
```

Based on requirement I want to extract common date and show it like

```
  RMG         11/02/2011      12/02/2011    13/02/2011
  YA           94                 32             32
  YB           63                 45             45
  YC           35                 51             51
```

How can I achieve this using table in Java or by SQL. I have no background in database. I am confused what is the best approach to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I find the matching dates to put it into `in(…)`?

The [pivot_in_clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) of `select` appears to accept a subquery, such as this:

```
select distinct(Date) from DbTable
```

Addendum: If XML is unacceptable with a subquery, a separate query may be used to determine the distinct values required. As a concrete example, the following method will return a `List` of unique dates from `DBTable`. The list is suitable for constructing the `IN` clause of the pivot.

```
private static List<Date> getDates(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.execute("select distinct(Date) from DbTable");
    ResultSet rset = st.getResultSet();
    while (rset.next()) {
        list.add(rset.getDate(1));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Addendum: Additional guidance may be found in the [JDBC™ Database Access](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) tutorial and the [*Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm).

Comment: I have tried to put subquery in pivot but failed in simple pivot...
it worked with XML keyword but I do not want in clob or long datatype ... I wanted to get in different-different columns...

if you can write please do this .. it would very helpful for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then run the `select distinct` query first and then use the result set to construct the `in` clause from the returned values.

Comment: will it create different columns??? I think it will not .... please if possible give example as well... I was trying to do this but failed ... if you can then please give sql statement...there should be one function for this but i don't know.. :( .. IT will helpful for anyone else also..

Comment: okay got now...
actually my question was how do create different different column for dynamic number of dates ... but i got you wanna to out that SQL query itself in java nature... right??
means after getting all distinct date you want to put every date in java program to prepare this kind of sql...
but if you know how to write such SQL please tell me..

Comment: I would use either `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` in the usual way.

Comment: again by java... :(
actually i was asking in pure oracle sql command if you know by any chance... thanks a lot for this idea also.. :)

Comment: @pratik garg: I've elaborated above. For reference, you may want to supply the coresponding PL/SQL in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If in this you are using oracle database then you can use PIVOT function to achive this , as below -

```
select * from JTable 
pivot(sum(value) for date in ('11-Feb-2011','12-Feb-2011','13-Feb-2011'));
```

hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to make it generic. I mean how can I find matching dates an put it into in(...) method at run time. Above was just example. There are plenty of records are there. I can not hard code.

Comment: I think in pure SQL there's no other way than explicit naming the columns for pivoting

Comment: thanks rabudde ..
What rabudde is telling is the right answer for your commented question....

there is no way in sql...
however i think in Pl/sql we can do this... but not tried yet in pl/sql as well.. :)

Comment: i have done and tested in PL/sql as well... in plsql we can do this kind of report... @Umesh Kacha let me know if you want that pl/sql code

Comment: @Pratik I want to build this kind of report in Java. I was just trying to get SQL logic so that I can code similar way in Java. That would be a great help if you share that query as I am novice in terms of SQL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Umesh as Pivot is used to make column but it has one limitation it will not allow you to put subquery in IN clouse..
please note that It means you have to hardcode your desired column name..
that's why for your situation in my knowlege you have to use PL/SQl only bbut i am confussed how to use this pl/ sql code in java...
???
i am not too good in Java.. please tell me if you can run pl/sql in java and fetch the print statement from pl/sql in java console??